# Transaction Per Second not increasing with more threads or servers using WCF

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I have a windows service which wakes up everyday at a particular time and finds around 100k transactions that it needs to process. It will spawn 25 threads, which look at the bucket of transactions that need to be processed and will make a call to a WCF service.

This WCF service will do some internal processing and make a synchronous call to an external service (which we have mocked and written an emulator for the sake of volume testing). Using this setup for shorter runs for around 10k transactions we were able to achieve a TPS of around 10.

I scaled this setup to have three load balanced servers running our WCF services and two other servers running the emulator, also we increased the number of threads on the windows service to 75 threads. With this new setup we expected an increase in performance, but the TPS is still at 10.

I have performance monitor running on all five machines. The three loaded balanced servers which have the WCF service are showing an "Outstanding Calls" of around 25 constantly in "ServiceModelService" category for the WCF service. But the two servers which have the emulators running show only around 9 "Outstanding Calls" constantly for the mocked out service. This same emulator was showing around 20 "Outstanding Calls" when it was running on a single server.

My questions are: 
Why is there no increase in TPS in the three load balanced machines setup? 
Where is the bottleneck in this system?

The target is to get to a TPS of around 30 with the three loaded balanced servers running the WCF service.

Note: I have increased the maxconnection limit in the web config on the WCF service and windows service to 200 which increased the TPS from around 6 to the current value of 10.

Edit: More information, if each of the load balanced server has 25 outstanding calls, shouldn't the mocked external service have 3*25=75 outstanding calls?

By maxconnection limit I meant:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="200" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: *I have increased the maxconnection limit in the web config* Doesn't sound like you're configuring the things that matter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, each of my servers is getting only a maximum of 25 concurrent calls from my windows service. The number of processors on the server is 2, so the maxConcurrent calls is 2*16=32 by default which is greater than the 25 concurrent calls that it is currently receiving. So, I think I haven't hit the upper limit of that setting for it to be an issue. What do you think?

Comment: If some part of the infrastructure throttles processing async IO will not help. It will fall under the same restriction. This is not your problem.; Whatever the limit is on the source servers, tripling their amount should triple the throughput iff they were the bottleneck. Apparently, they are not. How did you make sure that the LB and the target servers can take the load? Is this a fake workload (a sleep)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't give us enough information to diagnose the problem accurately. However, what you describe gives me enough to recommend some places to look.

First, you probably shouldn't be spawning 25 (or more) threads in your Windows service. Rather, you can have a single thread looking at the "bucket of transactions," and make [asynchronous calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the WCF service. You can control the number of concurrent transactions using a Semaphore. Something like:

```
Semaphore _transactionSemaphore = new Semaphore(25, 25);
while (transactionCount > 0)
{
    transactionSemaphore.WaitOne();  // wait for a free spot
    var transaction = getTransaction();
    DoAsyncWcfCall(transaction);
}
```

And the async completed event (see the above link about asynchronous calls) releases the semaphore:

```
void AsyncCompletedEvent(...)
{
    // do after-call processing
    // and then release the semaphore
    transactionSemaphore.Release();
}
```

When `transactionCount` gets to 0, you have to wait for all outstanding calls to complete. You do that by repeatedly waiting on the semaphore: 25 times. That is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
{
    transactionSemaphore.WaitOne();
}
```

If your main thread has gobbled up the semaphore, then you know that there can't be any outstanding calls.

You can extend that concurrent transaction count to 50 or 75, or whatever value you like. Your hardware being able to handle it, of course.

The difference here is that asynchronous service calls use I/O completion ports rather than individual threads. Allocating a thread that just sits there and waits is very wasteful. With the I/O completion port, the only time a thread gets involved is when the call completes--in the async completed method. Those threads are allocated automatically by the thread pool.

If the service is constantly showing 25 outstanding calls, then the total of outstanding calls for all of the servers better not be more than that. If the WCF services are showing more outstanding transactions than the Windows service is showing, then you have a problem. Come to think of it, if the service is showing *more* outstanding calls than do the load balanced servers, you also have a problem. If the two don't match, then somebody's dropping something: either the Windows service thinks that it has outstanding calls that the WCF services think are filled, or vice-versa.

It's hard to say where the bottleneck is. If you're experiencing high CPU usage on the Windows service machine, that's probably your bottleneck. You say that the WCF services call yet another external service. That external service could be the bottleneck. Depending on how you mocked it, the mock could be the bottleneck. Have you determined how much time that external service takes? That the services running the mocked service seem to have lower throughput than the WCF service that's talking to the real service makes me think there's a problem with performance of your mock.

I suppose it's possible that your WCF services aren't properly cleaning up resources, and they are spending an inordinate amount of time in garbage collection. Have you verified that you're using the [server garbage collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? I *think* that's the default for WCF services, but you need to check.

Given the information you've provided, I consider those the most likely possible bottlenecks.

One other thing. It's incredibly wasteful to have a Windows service that does nothing but sit there and once a day "wakes up" to process some transactions. You should make that a console application and [schedule a task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) to run it once per day. You can use the Task Scheduler GUI, or you can schedule it with the [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx) command. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Another benefit of making your program a console app rather than a service is that it's a whole lot easier to debug a console app.

Comment: We did discuss about Async calls before implementation but, went with the synchronous approach to keep it simple as we assumed we had reliable WCF services with fast response times. More information: a) in the load balanced setup I see 25 outstanding calls on each of the three load balanced servers with the WCF service. 3*25 = 75 threads on windows service. So, I am assuming that windows service is not bottling it up. b)I am not seeing high CPU usage on any of the servers.

Comment: c)Yes, the external service could be the bottleneck. But how can I confirm it? The external is running with a 2 second delay. I have tried it with a 1 sec delay, but the TPS does not improve. If there is a problem with my mock I expect the TPS to be low, but that does not explain how the mocked up service can only show only ~20 "outstanding calls". Shouldn't it be close to 75? d)As for the garbage collection, the total # of items that the GC seems to be collecting in gen0, 1 and 2 seems to be linear. I don't remember the time it was spending in GC. I can double check that and the server gc.

Comment: f) I simplified the windows service part, it actually wakes up every minute to see if it has any jobs to run, we have around 30 jobs that we run daily doing a variety of processing (the time at which they run is dependent on external factors and can vary daily). I do agree debugging console is a lot easier, but we have a good amount of reliable logging in the windows service to get the information we need to make sure everything is alright.

Comment: **I checked a stat called %time in gc in performance monitor and that is also very low, an average of 1.5 with a max spike of 30.

Comment: As far as your suggestion for the solution, I would consider it. But my first priority is to figure out where the bottleneck is. What if the bottleneck is not in the way my windows service operates?